# What is HTML5 Microdata?

Tags: html

I search many article on HTML 5 microdata but i ant got a clear view on that.Can somebody provide me a good article on that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark Pilgrim's [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) gives this definition:

> Microdata annotates the DOM with scoped name/value pairs from custom vocabularies.

Read the [whole section](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/extensibility.html) for further explanation and examples.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#microdata

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176035 and http://www.data-vocabulary.org/ are good resources.